# How to exit a state early from within a StateMachineBehevior?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mecanim

I have a StateMachineBehaviorScript that needs to check if an external boolean is true or false, and if false the current state needs to stop immediately to let the next state proceed.

I have tried using animator.StopPlayBack() if the condition is false and have tried it in both the entry and update but neither appear to be working, the animation still plays all the way through regardless of the boolean value. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    if (!isReady)
    {
        animator.StopPlayback();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a transition and call `animator.setTrigger()` etc. to initiate it. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In the animator settings make sure the option called Has Exit time is not checked.
Because if it is it will complete the current animation no matter what before start a new one.